# Processmaker 3.* Path Traversal Issue

Tags: php, security, processmaker, path-traversal

I have Processmaker 3.1.3 running into an RHEL-7 server. But recently I found that the server is vulnerable by path traversal attack. The entire application is running through the file `App.php` into the `$App_Dir/workflow/public_html` directory handling the url redirection and other operations. Currently, I'm using this piece of code to prevent the problem at the top of the `App.php` located into `$App_Dir/workflow/public_html`.

```
<?php
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
 $key = "../";  
   if (strpos($url, $key) == true) {   
     die("Forbiden");  
   }
?>
```

But I think this is not a perfect solution. The application might get stuck at any time. Any recommendation /Solution?

**TIA**

Answer (score 0):

This is not sufficient because the URL could be encode in so many format for "../".
You need to enforce your input validation to solve your issue.

1. You should use a function who will work with the realpath (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to obtain the path of your file.
2. You should after that validate the result path against your business rules. The list of the path allowed should be done in a whitelist approach (you should list all the directory you want) and not a blacklist approach (the one you present in your code).